# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory during Druid ingestion task

Tags: memory-management, jvm, druid

I'm ingesting data into Druid using Kafka ingestion task.
The test data is 1 message/second. Each message has 100 numeric columns and 100 string columns. Number values are random. String values are taken from a pool of 10k random 20 char strings. I have sum, min and max aggregations for each numeric column.

Config is the following:

- Segment granularity: 15 mins.
- Intermediate persist period: 2 mins.
- druid.processing.buffer.sizeBytes=26214400
- druid.processing.numMergeBuffers=2
- druid.processing.numThreads=1

The Druid docs say that sane max direct memory size is

> (druid.processing.numThreads + druid.processing.numMergeBuffers + 1) *
> druid.processing.buffer.sizeBytes

where "The + 1 factor is a fuzzy estimate meant to account for the segment decompression buffers and dictionary merging buffers."

According to the formula I need 100 MB of direct memory but I get **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory** even when I set max direct memory to 250 MB. This error is not consistent: sometimes I have this error, sometimes I don't.

My target is to calculate max direct memory before I start the task and to not get the error during task execution. My guess is that I need to calculate this "+1 factor" precisely. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, that formula has been pretty good, with the exception of being careful that a MB is not 1000 KB, but 1024. But I am quite surprised it still gave you the error with 250MB. How are you setting the direct memory size? And are you using a MiddleManager with Peons? Because the peons do the actual work, and you have to set the max direct memory on the peons, not the middle manager. You do it with the following parameter in the Middle Manager runtime.properties.  This is what I have on mine:

druid.indexer.runner.javaOptsArray=["-server", "-Xms200m", "-Xmx200m", "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=220m", "-Duser.timezone=UTC", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", "-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager", "-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError", "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "-XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/druid/task/"]

You also have to set the other properties this way too: druid.indexer.fork.property.druid.processing.buffer.sizeBytes druid.indexer.fork.property.druid.processing.numMergeBuffers
druid.indexer.fork.property.druid.processing.numThreads

Comment: Hi, I use MIddleManager with peons and set direct and heap memory for each supervisor separately using context object. I made sure each peon really uses amount of memory that was set and that the 1 MB is 1024KB in my calculations. I think there could be something not covered in Druid documentation about this memory usage.